# Redux toolkit reducer not receiving ( {action.payload} )

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

i am trying to make custom server side pagination on every click. but when i try to update state by using reducer i got this error

[image]

**COMPONENT FILE from where i am dispatching this reducer**

```
 function changePageByNumber(page){
      dispatch(pageByNumber({page:page})) //dispatching reducer
      dispatch(fetchUsers({page:page}));
    }
```

**SLICE FILE**

```
const usersSlice = createSlice({
name:'users',
initialState: usersAdapter.getInitialState( { loading: false, page: 1, total_pages: null } ),
reducers:{
  pageByNumber: (state,{action}) => {
    state.page = action.payload // why action not getting payload
  }
},
extraReducers: {
    [fetchUsers.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true
    },
    [fetchUsers.fulfilled]: (state, { payload}) => {
      state.loading = false,
      state.total_records = payload.total,
      state.per_page = payload.per_page,
      state.total_pages = payload.total/payload.per_page,
      usersAdapter.setAll(state, payload.data)      
    },
    [fetchUsers.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.loading = false
    }
  },
});

export const usersSelectors = usersAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => state.users,
  )

export const {pageByNumber} = usersSlice.actions
export default usersSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action object ***is*** the second argument passed to the reducer. There is no `action.action` so attempting to access into `action.action.payload` throws the error.

You should destructure the `payload` property from `action`:

```
pageByNumber: (state, action) => {
  state.page = action.payload;
}
```

or

```
pageByNumber: (state, { payload }) => {
  state.page = payload;
}
```

Based on the dispatched action `dispatch(pageByNumber({ page: page }))` I'd also say that you need to access the `page` property of the action payload:

```
pageByNumber: (state, action) => {
  state.page = action.payload.page;
}
```